# Plotting a function with a loop

Tags: arrays, function, loops, plot, modeling

I have this following code where i am basically calculating the MTTDL (Mean Time To Data Loss) of a hard drive. The print(sum(y)) gives me the MTTDL in hours.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

l12=0.00002
l23=0.02
l21=0.0769
l31=0.003

B= np.array([1,0]) * (-1)
Q= np.array([[-l12,l12],
             [l21,-l21-l23]])
y= np.matmul(B, np.linalg.inv(Q))
print (y)
print (sum(y))
```

I want my **l12 value** (only) which i have determined in the beginnning of a code  to begin from 0.000002 to 0.00004 with step 0.000002 (That's 20 different numbers in total). I know i should put a loop in the code but since i am beginner in python i am struggling to do so

Each time l12 changes the MTTDL(sum(y)) will change and i basically want to plot this relation between l12 and MTTDL(sum(y))

**The result should be looking like the graph here** [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEU0T.png)

Any advice fellas?

I am aware of the of the step sequence x=np.arange(0.000002,0.0004,0.000002) and i understand the logic behind it but i am sure where i should place it inside the code